# How to make SwiftUI so that there is a button in the text that opens a file with a document?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Clicking on the green text opens the document
How to do it like here:

[image]

```
HStack {
         checkBox1
            .foregroundColor(.green)
         Text("Даю свое Согласие на обработку персональных данных")
         Spacer()
}
```

Comment: If you need generic localisable solution then SwfitUI does not give such possibility and it should be used UIKit/NSAttributedString based solution. If you need it *only for one-language specific this case* then there are variants/workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible *restricted* approach (in SwiftUI-only), but might be appropriate in some scenarios (so I decided it worth posting)

The idea is to break text on known *to be clickable/non-clickable* parts and combining them *visually-only* disallow clicking for some overlaid.

On demo screenshot corresponding areas are bordered with colors.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoPartiallyClickedText: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "square")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            VStack {  // << any container
                Text("Даю свое").foregroundColor(.clear) +
                Text(" Согласие на обработку персональных данных").foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            .onTapGesture {          // allowed tap
                print(">> tapped")
            }
            .overlay(
                Text("Даю свое").contentShape(Rectangle())
                   .onTapGesture {},                   // << blocked !!
                alignment: .topLeading)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```